# Import JSON using WITH in Neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use a JSON, to eventually import it into Neo4j.

I use something like, it's a big JSON string:

```
WITH [
{"fullname":"Full name","note":"f","addr":[],"phone":[],"email":[{"value":"mail@city.com"}],"first_name":"","last_name":""},
..
] AS contacts
```

The colors of the first contact is mostly orange, then the other contacts become green, then black.

I get the following error:

```
Invalid input '"': expected whitespace, an identifier, UnsignedDecimalInteger, a property key name or '}'
```

I can view my JSON file with http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ And it looks fine

Do I need to escape some kind of character, so that Neo4j understands it?

**Edit:**

Based on Martins answer, I removed the quotes using a regex in PHP from:
[Remove double-quotes from a json_encoded string on the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837659/remove-double-quotes-from-a-json-encoded-string-on-the-keys)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotation marks around the keys. The error message tells you that it expects a `property key`. Cypher does not use JSON here.

```
WITH [
{fullname:"Full name",note:"f",addr:[],phone:[],
email:[{value:"mail@city.com"}],
first_name:"",last_name:""}
] AS contacts
RETURN contacts
```

A neo4j driver or client library will handle data passed from dictionary like structures as parameters: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters

If you want to work with JSON and maybe load it from external sources you should have a look at the APOC procedures: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/.

This for example converts a JOSN string to a map that can be used in Cypher: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_from_tojson

```
CALL apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(
'{"fullname":"Full name","note":"f","addr":[],"phone":[],
"email":[{"value":"mail@city.com"}],"first_name":"","last_name":""}'
) 
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

Comment: APOC procedures sounds handy for in the future, are internal sources also possible? If the file is on my VPS in the Neo4j folder?

Comment: There is no `LOAD JSON FROM ...`. You have to do this application side.