# JSON decode without double quotes for the string

Tags: php

```
c_id: 76523456,
output: {
    alert_level: 1,
    data: {
        volume: 56,
        date: '10th June 2016'
           },
    alert_level: 2,
    data: {
        volume: 26,
        date: '10th July 2016'
          }
       }
}
```

Can someone please help.  How can we apply double quotes via php code, then decode it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837659/remove-double-quotes-from-a-json-encoded-string-on-the-keys you can see this solution

Comment: It has multiple issues to become a valid json .. even if you apply double quotes `"` then also it will throw error of duplicate key.. So it needs to be controlled at generation point .. or are you getting it from some api ??

Comment: you can try typecasting. no idea about php in python i can do type casting as `str(dict.keys)`.

Answer (score -1):

> if i am not wrong this should be the structure of json what you are expecting ...

```
[{
    "alert_level": 1,
    "data": {
        "volume": 56,
        "date": "10th June 2016"
    }
}, {
    "alert_level": 2,
    "data": {
        "volume": 26,
        "date": "10th July 2016"
    }
}]
```

dict inside the list/Array

Comment: i dont know , the response , what i am getting from the url is the same . i am not able to decode it