# remove quote on echo json_encode();

Tags: php, json, ajax

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id=1");               
 $array = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
 $help_name = $array['name'];
 $req =   $array['req'];
 //fetch result    

 echo json_encode($help_name);
```

Problem is I'm getting the result with double quotes, how to remove the double quotes

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES)`
[PHP.net - Function htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: That's the only way that your string will be valid json. If you don't want quotes, don't encode it to json.

Comment: Please refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938645/remove-double-quote-in-json-encode] [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837659/remove-double-quotes-from-a-json-encoded-string-on-the-keys]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove double quote in json\_encode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938645/remove-double-quote-in-json-encode)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile - IMHO, this is not a duplicate. The linked question is more complex. It involves removing double-quotes from certain items within json_encoded data. This question is much simpler: it is simply the quotes around the whole string, when passing to `echo`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Try trim in php

```
<?php 
$name = "Aman";
$str = json_encode($name);
echo trim($str, '"');  // output : Aman
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$help_name = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $help_name);
```