# Writing string to screen without quotes in php

Tags: php

I am trying to write string to screen without quotes in php. I get the string data from a Mysql database and I try to write it to a textbox but double quotes are also written.

Example : `"a2"` .

i want that just write =>    `a2`   .

```
$gönder= (json_encode($gönder) );
    echo $gönder;
```

string data is `$gönder` .

Comment: Why the json_encode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove quote on echo json\_encode();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509179/remove-quote-on-echo-json-encode)

Comment: You didn't ask any question.

Comment: i writing  to $gönder another html page with ajax . so i use json_encode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like this :

```
echo trim($gönder, '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$gönder` is a string, `json_encode($gönder)` will wrap it in double quotes.

Just `echo` it before applying `json_encode`:

```
$gönder = 'a2';
echo $gönder; // a2
$gönder = json_encode($gönder);
echo $gönder; // "a2"
```

Answer (score 0):

### use this code

echo trim($gönder, '"');