# Remove double quotes after a slash in json_encode()

Tags: php, json, cakephp-3.0

I get information from database and create a json for user to download. But got problem with json downloaded
My code in CakePHP

```
        $response = json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->viewBuilder()->className('Json');
        $this->response->download('export-' . date('YmdHis') . '.' . "json");
        $this->set('_jsonOptions', JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $this->set(compact('response'));
        $this->set('_serialize', "response");
```

Expected:

> {"version":"1.0","name":"test","value":"abc123"}

Result

> {\"version\":\"1.0\",\"name\":\"test\",\"value\":\"abc123\"}

Comment: Already refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837659/remove-double-quotes-from-a-json-encoded-string-on-the-keys?rq=1 but maybe not match requirement

Comment: Are you sure `$result` is an array? What does `var_dump($result);` give you exactly?

Comment: Im not a cake user, but a cursory google (and just looking at your code) suggests Cake uses json_encode internally, so just pass it unencoded data: `$this->set(['response'=>$result]);`

Comment: Your setting the value in `$response` but this variable isn't directly referred to again, so is there some other processing going on?

Comment: @jeroen: var_dump give me correct format, $result is array because I try to hardcode an array there to test.

Comment: @Steve: Awesome!!! Thank you!

Comment: @NguyenTrongViet No problem, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

try this with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT parameter

```
<?php
    $fruits = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry'); // fruits table
    echo json_encode($fruits, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    // {"0":"apple","1":"orange","2":"banana","3":"strawberry"} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using CakePHP 2.x, I ran into this issue. This is how I solved it.

```
function blah1()
{
    $data = ['path' => '/i/have/no/escaped/slashes'];
    $this->set('_jsonOptions', JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    $this->set([ '_serialize' => 'data', 'data' => $data]) ;
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "path":"/i/have/no/escaped/slashes"
}
```

Escaped slashes

```
function blah2()
{
    $data = ['path' => '/i/have/escaped/slashes'];
    $this->set([ '_serialize' => 'data', 'data' => $data]) ;
}
```

Output:

```
{"path":"\/i\/have\/escaped\/slashes"}
```